# how to load thumbnail images of products in Prestashop rest web service

Tags: xml, web-services, rest, thumbnails, prestashop-1.6

I want to load images of different sizes for products like smaller sizes.

I am downloading images through prestashop 1.6 rest web services in xml format which are of 500 * 500 resolution.

I want know the links to **thumbnails** of products which I can download through xml format.

I am aware that there various sizes available depending upon image type "image_types", but how to access them? The prestashop documentation is also unclear.

Is there any way to do so?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call it like:

`api/images/products/1/1/cart_default`

The full list is: "cart_default", "home_default", "large_default", "medium_default", "small_default", "thickbox_default"